# Coaxing GCC to emit REPE CMPSB

Tags: c, performance, gcc, assembly, x86

How to coax the GCC compiler to emit the REPE CMPSB instruction in plain C, without the "asm" and "_emit" keywords, calls to an included library and compiler intrinsics?

I tried some C code like the one listed below, but unsuccessfully:

```
unsigned int repe_cmpsb(unsigned char *esi, unsigned char *edi, unsigned int ecx) {

    for (; ((*esi == *edi) && (ecx != 0)); esi++, edi++, ecx--); 

    return ecx;
}
```

See how GCC compiles it at this link:
https://godbolt.org/g/obJbpq

P.S.
I realize that there are no guarantees that the compiler compiles a C code in a certain way, but I'd like to coax it anyway for fun and just to see how smart it is.

Comment: Without using `asm` presumably?

Comment: Correct - without using the asm directive ;)

Comment: `rep cmpsb` isn't fast; it's >= 2 cycles per byte throughput on Haswell, for example.  (http://agner.org/optimize).  Only `rep movs` and `rep stos` have "fast strings" support in current x86 CPUs.  The "smart" thing for modern CPUs is to use SSE2 `pcmpeqb`.  (But gcc and clang don't know how to vectorize loops with an iteration count that isn't known before loop entry; i.e. they can't vectorize search loops.  ICC can, though.)

Comment: @PeterCordes interestingly instlatx64 [says](http://users.atw.hu/instlatx64/GenuineIntel00306C3_HaswellXeon_InstLatX64.txt) Haswell can do 1 bye / cycle, I wonder which is right?

Comment: @harold: That says *bandwidth in L1D*.  So they mean 2 cycles for 1 byte from each string.  Agner describes it as cycles per `n = ecx`, i.e. cycles per compare (and that's what I meant by per byte; I didn't realize the ambiguity).  InstLatx64 lists the `rep lodsb` bandwidth as 0.5 bytes / cycle, which is consistent with Agner's `~2n` number for `rep lods` throughput.

Comment: @PeterCordes oh yes, that makes sense

Answer (score 10):

`rep cmps` isn't fast; it's >= 2 cycles per count throughput on Haswell, for example, plus startup overhead.  (http://agner.org/optimize).  You can get a regular byte-at-a-time loop to go at 1 compare per clock (modern CPUs can run 2 loads per clock) even when you have to check for a match and for a `0` terminator, if you write it carefully.

[InstLatx64 numbers agree](http://users.atw.hu/instlatx64/GenuineIntel00306C3_HaswellXeon_InstLatX64.txt): Haswell can manage 1 cycle per byte for `rep cmpsb`, but that's total bandwidth (i.e. 2 cycles to compare 1 byte from each string).

---

**Only `rep movs` and `rep stos` have "fast strings" support** in current x86 CPUs.  (i.e. microcoded implementations that internally use wider loads/stores when alignment and lack of overlap allow.)

The "smart" thing for modern CPUs is to use SSE2 `pcmpeqb` / `pmovmskb`.  (But gcc and clang don't know how to vectorize loops with an iteration count that isn't known before loop entry; i.e. they can't vectorize search loops.  ICC can, though.)

---

**However, gcc will for some reason inline `repz cmpsb` for `strcmp` against short fixed strings**.  Presumably it doesn't know any smarter patterns for inlining `strcmp`, and the startup overhead may still be better than the overhead of a function call to a dynamic library function.  Or maybe not, I haven't tested.  Anyway, it's not horrible for code size in a block of code that compares something against a bunch of fixed strings.

```
#include <string.h>

int string_equal(const char *s) {
    return 0 == strcmp(s, "test1");
}
```

[gcc7.3 -O3 output from Godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAKxAEZSAbAQwDtRkBSAJgCFufSAZ1QBXYskwgA5NwDMeAGYBqAAwcVAQREtBeYC0zoleFgSXFMAB0wB9ZAFtLggEYQ0Os9t37DS5AiZiJQAqC0ECYjxkM0xdUj9UDyUvPQMjf0CQsIiomPx4lJ8jExjkAA8ASnUNDgB2Pk0laqUWpQUSJQgOWR5OiGDYvCbZABFukZDDPAqmrgA2bjnOzHKlMDBx1QqqnqVB/n54qYPeI/KAWnOd3urm1osCMRY98u6GmtqxzWqSpQJYgi0OZuRLhZI6VK%2BDJBUIAyLRJSCeLuMGFNJ%2BAIw7LwszoKrferVAD0RJaaKhmMRHAArDwgTSxj1iaTwd50dClOgaXSFtTGe8WncHk9zFZbA4nK4kZz4kDrrdPrcuLJMCx8Apbt9lSZkAwRFhhgBhcKRNgAOgQ3Wwmo0vxNJmANkwAEcREwGCCkhzgoIZnUBa0SUoABxKZwAT3%2BiJybE6Or1%2BFjNMNKhmggQogYRndDFQAHdRZYAF5%2BRyCLmNQOkjpMREOhiYJTOvMkdKOYweYgiaJ4RLrO4tYXEZ4qYaMiYmiUQaXcLj/cK0ZWz%2BUEr41TR2mOOqcosze31NQmVweYR7D6PiRzT%2BKz%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%2BYFyUhddxBJZF0WqgQ8WJVlaHpZlyXZSsvX5cZyVFSVZVSJFlX03ptX1Yw6XNUTpxre18BdT1fVG4Nw3beNU0zecc0LYE/jjAEgh5lVDC/UJANA1IrHsaD0jg5D0PGPDSji8j%2BBEHjyoY1jON57IT6Y/xJMWWTFMKTTNPqVpidM9ILOmeZXFk/TXCM3pzNs5XTH5cQuiJCAGlAA%3D)

```
.LC0:
    .string "test1"
string_cmp:
    mov     rsi, rdi
    mov     ecx, 6
    mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
    repz cmpsb
    setne   al
    movzx   eax, al
    ret
```

If you don't booleanize the result somehow, gcc generates a -1 / 0 / +1 result with seta / setb / sub / movzx.  (Causing a partial-register stall on Intel before IvyBridge, and a false dependency on other CPUs, because it uses 32-bit `sub` on the `setcc` results, /facepalm.  Fortunately most code only needs a 2-way result from strcmp, not 3-way).

gcc only does this with fixed-length string constants, otherwise it wouldn't know how to set `rcx`.

---

**The results are totally different for `memcmp`: gcc does a pretty good job**, in this case using a DWORD and a WORD `cmp`, with no rep string instructions.

```
int cmp_mem(const char *s) {
    return 0 == memcmp(s, "test1", 6);
}

    cmp     DWORD PTR [rdi], 1953719668  # 0x74736574
    je      .L8
.L5:
    mov     eax, 1
    xor     eax, 1          # missed optimization here after the memcmp pattern; should just xor eax,eax
    ret
.L8:
    xor     eax, eax
    cmp     WORD PTR [rdi+4], 49     # check last 2 bytes
    jne     .L5
    xor     eax, 1
    ret
```

---

**Controlling this behaviour**

[The manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Options.html) says that `-mstringop-strategy=libcall` should force a library call, but it doesn't work.  No change in asm output.

Neither does `-mno-inline-stringops-dynamically -mno-inline-all-stringops`.

It seems this part of the GCC docs is obsolete.  I haven't investigated further with larger string literals, or fixed size but non-constant strings, or similar.

Comment: Thanks for the long answer.  It is interesting to note that repe cmpsb can be slower than some other code in a loop (e.g.: ?) but I don't think anything can beat repe cmpsb in terms of code size. Do you concur?

Comment: @KarolaN: For short compile-time-constant strings, gcc's `memcmp` strategy (`cmp [mem], imm32`) is competitive, if you're counting code + rodata size.  There's more overhead per string byte with immediates, though.  It avoids the setup code, e.g. `mov ecx, 6` is 5 bytes.  (If you're optimizing for code-size, you'd `xor eax,eax` / `lea ecx, [rax+6]` (5 bytes), and that avoids the `movzx` after the `setcc al`.  Of course, normally you'd just branch on flags directly instead of using setcc, so you might `push 6` / `pop rcx` (3 bytes) if optimizing for code-size without caring about performance.

Comment: Peter, I'd like to mark your answer as THE ANSWER, but it is missing a crucial piece, namely any plain C code (without opaque libcalls), that will compile to repe cmpsb.  It doesn't have to be repe cmpsb alone.  A repe cmpsw or repe cmpsd or even a different compiler than GCC is fine, too.

Comment: I think the part at the top explaining why gcc/clang wouldn't want to do that for any of the current CPUs it cares about tuning for, for performance reasons, is the real answer, especially for non-tiny strings.  Maybe clang `-Oz` (code-size regardless of performance) would benefit from that, if anyone's bothered to implement that pattern.  But I wouldn't expect that anyone *has* implemented it, because it's a lot of code (in the compiler) to find such patterns but it's only useful for rare cases like code-size over speed.

Comment: Update: [Why is this code using strlen heavily 6.5x slower with GCC optimizations enabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55563598) is a case where GCC's inline expansion using `rep scasb` at `-O1` is disastrous for performance.  That's since been fixed; GCC doesn't do that anymore.