# A better form to find a Substring in a string in assembly code (MASM)?

Tags: string, assembly, masm, strstr

So i made this code with the knowledge i gather in various sites, i think there is an optimazed way to do it without pushing and poping the registers on the stack memory, but i don't know how to do it.
**Here is my Code**

```
comparing proc
    MOV CX, SIZEOF vec2 ;The size of the substring
    DEC CX
    MOV DX, SIZEOF vec1 ; The size of the String
    LEA SI, vec1        ; The String
    LEA DI, vec2        ; The substring

FIND_FIRST:        
    MOV AL, [SI];   storing the ascii value of current character of mainstring 
    MOV AH, [DI];   storing the ascii value of current character of substring
    CMP AL,AH;      comparing both character
    JE FITTING;      if we find it we try to find the whole substring
    JNE NEXT

NEXT:
    INC SI; We go to the next char
    DEC DX; And the size of the string decreased
    JE N_FINDED
    JMP FIND_FIRST
FITTING:
    CLD
    PUSH CX ; I push this register because in the instruction REPE CMPSB
    PUSH SI ; They change.
    PUSH DI
    REPE CMPSB
    JNE N_FITTING
    JE FINDED
N_FITTING:
    POP DI
    POP SI
    POP CX
    JMP NEXT ; if the complete substring doesn't fit we go to the next char
FINDED:
    POP DI
    POP SI
    POP CX
    MOV AL, 0001H;  substring found
    JMP RETURN


N_FINDED:    
    MOV AL, 0000H;  substring not found

RETURN:
    ret 
comparing endp
```

Comment: For what it's worth, the supine of "find" is "found".

Comment: In terms of micro-optimizations, you can hoist `cld` and `push`/`pop` out of the loop, only saving/restoring around the whole function.  Also, scanning for a matching first byte before starting a slow `rep cmpsb` would make a lot of sense.  (In fact, on modern CPUs, `rep cmps` and `rep scas` aren't optimized with fast-strings microcode, only `rep stos` and `rep movs`, so generally avoid them entirely; [see this example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55563598) of an old version of GCC that inlines `rep cmpsb` at `-O1`, being slow for large strlen especially vs. SSE2 SIMD.

Comment: In terms of algorithmic optimizations, for a long substring "needle", there are algorithms that can do better than just looking at every byte of the "haystack" as a possible start point.  A famous one is Boyer-Moore.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string-search_algorithm.  Or without really changing the brute-force strategy, to use `cmp [si], ax` or something to check for 2 matching bytes, with overlapping unaligned word compares.  Are you optimizing for actual 8086, or for modern x86 in 16-bit mode?  Or somewhere in between like 386 or Pentium?

Answer (score 1):

If the substring happens to have more than one character, which is very likely, then **your code will start comparing bytes that are beyond the string to search through**.
With the string referred to by `DI` and its length `DX`, and the substring referred to by `SI` and its length `CX`, you first need to make sure that neither string is empty, and then you need to limit the number of possible finds. Next 4 lines of code do just that:

```
    jcxz NotFound   ; Substring is empty
    sub  dx, cx
    jb   NotFound   ; Substring is longer than String
                    ; Happens also when String is empty
    inc  dx
```

As an example consider the string "overflow" (`DX=8`) and the substring "basic" (`CX=5`):

```
sub  dx, cx    ; 8 - 5 = 3
inc  dx        ; 3 + 1 = 4  Number of possible finds is 4

overflow

basic       possible find number 1
 basic      possible find number 2
  basic     possible find number 3
   basic    possible find number 4
```

---

You can write your proc **without having to preserve those registers on the stack (or elsewhere) all the time**. Just introduce another register so you don't have to clobber the `CX`, `SI`, and `DI` registers:

```
    jcxz NotFound
    sub  dx, cx
    jb   NotFound
    inc  dx

    mov  al, [si]       ; Permanent load of first char of the Substring
FirstCharLoop:
    cmp  [di], al
    je   FirstCharMatch
NextFirstChar:
    inc  di
    dec  dx             ; More tries?
    jnz  FirstCharLoop  ; Yes
NotFound:
    xor  ax, ax
    ret

FirstCharMatch:
    mov  bx, cx
    dec  bx
    jz   Found          ; Substring had only 1 character
OtherCharsLoop:
    mov  ah, [si+bx]
    cmp  [di+bx], ah
    jne  NextFirstChar
    dec  bx
    jnz  OtherCharsLoop
Found:
    mov  ax, 1
    ret
```

Do note that this code now does not compare the first character again like the `repe cmpsb` in your program did.
`AX` being the result, the only registers that are clobbered (and that you maybe could want to preserve) are `BX`, `DX`, and `DI`.