# nasm zero byte omitted at the end of the string

Tags: string, assembly, nasm, null-terminated

I am studying Assembly language using this [nasm tutorial](https://asmtutor.com/). Here is the code that prints a string:

```
SECTION .data
msg     db      'Hello!', 0Ah

SECTION .text
global  _start

_start:

    mov     ebx, msg
    mov     eax, ebx

    ; calculate number of bytes in string
nextchar:
    cmp     byte [eax], 0
    jz      finished
    inc     eax
    jmp     nextchar

finished:
    sub     eax, ebx    ; number of bytes in eax now 

    mov     edx, eax    ; number of bytes to write - one for each letter plus 0Ah (line feed character)
    mov     ecx, ebx    ; move the memory address of our message string into ecx
    mov     ebx, 1      ; write to the STDOUT file
    mov     eax, 4      ; invoke sys_write (kernel opcode 4)
    int     80h

    mov     ebx, 0      ; no errors
    mov     eax, 1      ; invoke sys_exit (kernel opcode 1)
    int     80h
```

It works and successfully prints "Hello!\n" to STDOUT. One thing I don't understand: it searches for `\0` byte in `msg`, but we didn't define it. Ideally, the correct message definition should be

```
msg     db      'Hello!', 0Ah, 0h
```

How does it successfully get the zero byte at the end of the string?

The similar case is in [exercise 7](https://asmtutor.com/#lesson7):

```
; String printing with line feed function
sprintLF:
    call    sprint
 
    push    eax         ; push eax onto the stack to preserve it while we use the eax register in this function
    mov     eax, 0Ah    ; move 0Ah into eax - 0Ah is the ascii character for a linefeed
    push    eax         ; push the linefeed onto the stack so we can get the address
    mov     eax, esp    ; move the address of the current stack pointer into eax for sprint
    call    sprint      ; call our sprint function
    pop     eax         ; remove our linefeed character from the stack
    pop     eax         ; restore the original value of eax before our function was called
    ret                 ; return to our program
```

It puts just 1 byte: `0Ah` into `eax` without terminating `0h`, but the string length is calculated correctly inside `sprint`. What is the cause?

Comment: Try adding another string after `msg` and compare the difference.  You'll find that `nasm` just padds the `.data` section with NUL bytes to 4 kB.

Comment: Yup, that first case is a bug in the tutorial, relying on a coincidence of assembler + linker behaviour and the fact that you're not linking any other files with a `.data` section. (There are some other tutorial links in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info, but I forget if any of the NASM ones listed there are any good.)

Comment: In the 2nd case, `push 0Ah` is a 4-byte dword push whose high 3 bytes are zeros.  That *is* correct.  (But an inefficient way to implement `push 0Ah`.)

Comment: @PeterCordes What is an efficient way to implement it?

Comment: With `push 0Ah`, instead of `mov eax, 0Ah` / `push eax`.  :P  And since you asked about efficiency, nextchar at least uses a pointer increment instead of having two `inc` instructions in the loop, but can only run at 1 iter/clock on Haswell and later because it has two branches in the loop.  See [Why are loops always compiled into "do...while" style (tail jump)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47783926)

Comment: And of course searching 1 byte at a time is garbage on modern x86, where we can easily check 16 bytes at a time with SSE2, if we have alignment to avoid crossing into an unmapped page after the end of the string.  [Is it safe to read past the end of a buffer within the same page on x86 and x64?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37800739) / [Why is this code using strlen heavily 6.5x slower with GCC optimizations enabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55563598)